# Setting current culture for entire solution

Tags: c#, multilingual, culture

I'm trying to support multiple languages in a solution that has multiple projects and threads.

I have 2 resource files, one with English strings, and one with French strings.

I'm setting the current culture as follows:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(isEnglish ? "en-US" : "fr-CA");
```

Is there a way to set the current culture globally, for the entire solution, or do I have to do this for each thread that needs to access strings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In .NET Framework 4.5, the [CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gets or sets the default culture for threads in the current application domain.

> In the .NET Framework 4 and previous versions, by default, the culture
>   of all threads is set to the Windows system culture. For applications
>   whose current culture differs from the default system culture, this
>   behavior is often undesirable. In the .NET Framework 4.5, the
>   DefaultThreadCurrentCulture property enables an application to define
>   the default culture of all threads in an application domain.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a globalization section within system.Web in the web.config

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the `CurrentThread` it is set for the duration of the application. Just make sure you do it before you initialize any `UI`. Look into this [MSDN blog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b28bx3bh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for further information.